# NetworkManager showing different information than ip command

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I'm trying to work out why I cannot create a bridge (asked separately [Unable to create bridge using NetworkManager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772475/unable-to-create-bridge-using-networkmanager) ).

I think something is interferring with NetworkManager but I cannot tell what it is.

I want to disconnect the ethernet device and bring the interface down.

Running `nmcli dev disconnect enp42s0` or `nmcli con down enp42s0` then `nmcli c`

Shows the ethernet device is disconnected.

```
DEVICE            TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION  
enp42s0           ethernet  disconnected            --
```

but then the output of `ip a` shows the device is UP, althoguh without an ip address assigned.

```
3: enp42s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My question here is:
is this normal behaviour?

I have `systemd-networkd` disabled and stopped.

Comment: That is normal behavior.