# Unable to create bridge using NetworkManager

Tags: networking, networkmanager, bridge

I'm trying to work out why I cannot create a bridge for my Virtual Machines using `NetworkManager`.

I have now searched in several places for how to create a bridge network using `NetworkManager` to the point I cannot refer to a single tutorial. They are all more or less the same. Here are the steps that I do.

1. Disconnect ethernet

   ```
   nmcli dev disconnect enp42s0
   ```
2. Create bridge and slave

   ```
   nmcli con add type bridge ifname br0 con-name br0 autoconnect yes connection.zone home
   nmcli con modify enp42s0 master br0 connection.zone home
   ```
3. Connect bridge and slave

   ```
   nmcli con up br0
   nmcli con up enp42s0-slave
   ```

Everything is successful except for the last command. It shows the following error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown error
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=658de29d-4809-4113-9aa9-1f3f32ae40eb + NM_DEVICE=enp42s0' to get more details.
```

`journalctl` logs are not much more useful:

```
device (enp42s0): Activation: starting connection 'enp42s0-slave' (658de29d-4809-4113-9aa9-1f3f32ae40eb)
device (enp42s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp42s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp42s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp42s0): Activation: connection 'enp42s0-slave' could not be enslaved
device (enp42s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp42s0): released from master device br0
device (enp42s0): Activation: failed for connection 'enp42s0-slave'
device (enp42s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

For context I also asked this related question: [NetworkManager showing different information than ip command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772474/networkmanager-showing-different-information-than-ip-command)

Comment: Since you mention this is inside a virtual machine, and the error is `connection 'enp42s0-slave' could not be enslaved`, you should include information on how the network interface `enp42s0` is configured from your hypervisor.

Comment: This is not inside a virtual machine. It is the hypervisor networking itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe this solved my problem!

```
sudo reboot
```

--- Facepalm ---

The reason why this did not happen earlier is that I kept deleting the bridge and slave, as it did not appeared to be working.